# Shared ViewModel lateinit variable not initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

I have created a View Model :

```
class ShareUserVM : ViewModel() {
    lateinit var previousPath: UserPreviousPath
}

enum class UserPreviousPath {
    SIGN_IN,
    SIGN_UP,
    PROFILE
}
```

I am initializing this lateinit variable in Profile Fragment,SignIN Fragment and SignUp Fragment before going to EnterUserDetails Fragment
In EnterUserDetails.kt :

```
class EnterUserDetails {
.
.
.
    private val sharedUserVM: ShareUserVM by activityViewModels()
.
.
.
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?) :View {
.
.
.
shouldAuthenticate = sharedUserVM.previousPath == UserPreviousPath.PROFILE
.
.
.
}
```

So when I am opening EnterUserDetailsFragment.kt, it is opening fine and but when I open another app on my phone and come back to this app after around 5-10 mins this app crashes saying
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: 'lateinit property previousPath has not been initialized'

Comment: Where do you initialize `previousPath`?

Comment: I am initializing it in Profile Fragment,SignIN Fragment and SignUp Fragment before navigating to EnterUserDetails Fragment

Comment: hmm.. I guess the Activity gets detroyed and rebuild by Android. I think you need to do something with `onSaveInstanceState` but I'm not that familiar with it myself

Comment: I have put a Log in onDestroy() it is not coming up and also fragment is created again. I am having only one activity on top of that I have created many fragments, So I guess activity is not destroyed

Comment: I don't know what is then, sorry. Maybe someone else here can answer you

Comment: looks like you have to use nullable field like `var previousPath: UserPreviousPath?` or check is property was initialized `::sharedUserVM.isInitialized && sharedUserVM.previousPath == UserPreviousPath.PROFILE`

Comment: But I want to use previousPath to decide which Fragment to go when user press Back  Arrow Button from EnterUserDetailsFragment
If previousPath == PROFILE, I should take user to ProfileFragment and same goes for SignIn and SignUp. That's why I can't keep previousPath as nullable

Comment: And also I need previousPath to display user that his/her details have been updated if previousPath==UserPreviousPath.PROFILE and if it is equal to SignIn or SignUp I should take them to HomeScreenFragment